# Как отправить сгенерированный штрих код в телеграмм при помощи бота на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

не могу выполнить задачу, у меня есть алгоритм который генерирует штрих код, но мне нужно, чтобы код генерировался из сообщения, который присылает пользователь в телеграмм бота и по этому коду генерировалось изображение штрих-кода в формате png и отправлялось обратно в бота. Помогите.

```
def generate_ean13():
    digits = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(12)]

    odd_sum = sum(digits[0::2])
    even_sum = sum(digits[1::2])
    control_sum = (odd_sum * 3 + even_sum) % 10
    control_sum = (10 - control_sum) if control_sum != 0 else 0

    barcode = digits + [control_sum]

    barcode_str = ''.join(map(str, barcode))

    return barcode_str


barcode = generate_ean13()
print(barcode)

data = barcode
barcode_gen = EAN13(data)
with open("EAN-13.png", "wb") as f:
    EAN13(barcode, writer=ImageWriter()).write(f)
```

Comment: Данный код генерирует штрих-код путём генерации самого кода с помощью алгоритма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `BytesIO` и `aiogram` вот так:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import InputFile
from aiogram.utils import executor
from pybarcodes import EAN13
from io import BytesIO

bot = Bot(token="ТВОЙ_ТОКЕН")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


def generate_ean13(digits):
    odd_sum = sum(digits[0::2])
    even_sum = sum(digits[1::2])
    control_sum = (odd_sum * 3 + even_sum) % 10
    control_sum = (10 - control_sum) if control_sum != 0 else 0

    barcode = digits + [control_sum]

    barcode_str = ''.join(map(str, barcode))

    return barcode_str


def generate_image_barcode(code):
    barcode = generate_ean13(code)
    data = barcode
    barcode_gen = EAN13(data)
    file = BytesIO()
    file.name = 'code.png'
    barcode_gen.image.save(file, 'PNG')
    file.seek(0)
    return file


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Отправь 12 цифр от 0 до 9.")


@dp.message_handler()
async def generate(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.isnumeric() and len(message.text) == 12:
        digits = [int(s) for s in message.text]
        photo = InputFile(generate_image_barcode(digits))
        await message.answer_photo(photo)
    else:
        await message.answer("Отправь 12 цифр от 0 до 9.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: У меня выдаёт ошибки при вводе кода

Comment: @Alexsandr какие?

Comment: Пропишу в отдельном ответе ошибки, которые выводит мне консоль

Comment: @Alexsandr вам нужно установить Pillow версии ниже чем 10 используйте `pip install Pillow==9.5.0`

Comment: Установил, но у меня вывело Check the permissions

Comment: Нужно запустить проект через админа или через командную строку с правилами админа?

Comment: @Alexsandr проверьте что Pillow 9.5.0 не установился если да то проверьте что не запущен код который использует библиотеку и попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: всё запустилось и прекрасно работает. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-12' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError("'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55.1\test_bot.py", line 44, in generate
photo = InputFile(generate_image_barcode(digits))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55.1\test_bot.py", line 30, in generate_image_barcode
barcode_gen.image.save(file, 'PNG')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\pybarcodes\barcode.py", line 46, in image
return self._get_barcode_image()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\55\venv\Lib\site-packages\pybarcodes\barcode.py", line 153, in _get_barcode_image
text_width, _ = draw.textsize(self.code, font)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите